# Can't figure out why React code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've built a custom `Input` component which is simply a wrapper for the HTML `input` element.  Here's the critical code, which I've simplified for posting here:

```
// @flow

import React, { useState } from 'react';

type Props = {
  value?: string,
  onChange: Function
};

const Input = ((props: Props) => {
  const [ currentValue, setCurrentValue ] = useState(!!props.value ? props.value : '');

  const handleChange = (event: SyntheticInputEvent<EventTarget>) => {
    setCurrentValue(event.target.value);
    props.onChange(event);
  };

  return <input type='text'
                value={currentValue}
                onChange={handleChange} />;
});
```

I wrote a bunch of React Testing Library tests for this and they all pass fine.  But when I implemented this component in a web page, the initial value failed to appear.  I solved the problem by dropping the `currentValue` code and just using `props.value` instead.  That solves it.  But I'm most curious why this approach above fails to display the initial value.

Comment: What do you mean "the initial value failed to appear"? I'm seeing it.

Comment: With my team's app, the initial values never appear.

Comment: For future reference, it's a little bit strange that you're taking `value` and `onChange` props (like a controlled component) as well as using state (like an uncontrolled component). Either approach is fine, but usually they don't go together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-frost-rc40i), I did use `prop-types`

Comment: Very interesting.  I can not currently explain why it doesn't work with my team's app.